# calling to action from dynamically generated select box using ajax is not working?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax

I want to dynamically generate select box and on change event I want to call action class. getInvcId is generating select box dynamically and on change event of it, is not sending request to action.

```
         <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $.post('getInvcId',function(res){
                    var id=res.split(",");
                    var newOptions=[];
                    newOptions.push("<option value=''>Select Invoice ID</option>");
                    $.each(id, function(key,value){
                    if(value!=="")
                    {
                        newOptions.push("<option value='"+value+"'>"+value+"</option>");
                    }
                    $("#invcnum").html(newOptions.join(''));
                    });
                });
                $.post('payBkid',function(res){
                    var id=res.split(",");
                    var newOptions=[];
                    newOptions.push("<option value=''>Select Booking ID</option>");
                    $.each(id, function(key,value){
                    if(value!=="")
                    {
                        newOptions.push("<option value='"+value+"'>"+value+"</option>");
                    }
                    $("#bkid").html(newOptions.join(''));
                    });
                });
                $("#invcnum").on('change',function(){
                   var invc=$("#invcnum").val();
                   var data={'invoice':invc};
                   $.post('searchPayment', data, function(res){
                       alert("hello");
                   });
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: Your code looks okay, fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/1ajxkggp/

Comment: no data being sent in first 2 posts. Easy to see also when you inspect request itself in browser console network tab and see nothing being sent

Comment: but I am calling action class but it is not reaching to action class. It is just showing alert.

Comment: thanks charlietfl but in the first two posts I am not sending data , I just want to load <options> of select boxes from DB